# Sending an SMS as soon as recieving new email in PHP

Tags: php, cron

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [email checking and then act upon script for reacting to a sms message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338129/email-checking-and-then-act-upon-script-for-reacting-to-a-sms-message)

Suppose that I have two functions called `recieve_email()` and `send_sms()`.

The problem is that I should send SMS **as soon as** a new email arrives.

As I have researched, there are these 2 solutions:

- Checking emails using a cron job
- Checking emails using a web page that is always open using javascript (like gmail)

I think that the more stable way is the cron job.

I want to know is that aceptable to run a cron job **EVERY SINGLE MINUTE**? Or does it kill the server and bounce my site away?!

What about running the cron job every two minutes?! :D

**Question 2:**

Is there an `on_mail_recieved` like solution? It will be of course faster and optimum.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338129/email-checking-and-then-act-upon-script-for-reacting-to-a-sms-message  same basic problem.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the duplicate. I did always search SO, except this time that I only googled the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know is that aceptable to run a cron job EVERY SINGLE MINUTE? Or does it kill the server and bounce my site away?!

Generally, that's fine. If there's a chance the job will take longer than a minute you should generally implement a lock file or semaphore to prevent it from running multiple instances at the same time.

> Is there an on_mail_recieved like solution? It will be of course faster and optimum.

Yes, you can pipe e-mails through to a script. This requires you to run a mail server and can be a little involved technically.